# Sublime build Python in venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext

I set up a venv, then pip-installed a package and running my own Python script on it - all on a Windows PC.

When I run it directly in the windows console it works fine.
However if I try to build it with Sublime Text (Build System: Anaconda Python Builder) it throws me following error-message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycoingecko'
```

Any idea what is causing the issue and how I can avoid it?

Comment: try installing `pycoingecko` in conda environment using `conda install pycoingecko` or `pip install pycoingecko`. it looks like your anaconda don't have package `pycoingecko`.

Comment: Did you set up your Anaconda Build System to point to the venv instead of your system installation of Python? That's most likely the problem

Comment: @MattDMo not sure where can I do this? Havent done it consciously.. sorry I am beginner 

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. I happened to find a duplicate that I answered a while ago that will work for your situation, regardless of whether you use `conda` or `venv`.